# Keeping name when eliminating row in data frame

Tags: r

```
data1=c(1,8,7,3,2)
data1=data.frame(data1)
rownames(data1)=c("Johnny","May","Jenna","Aisha","Sharon")
```

I would like to eliminate rows that have value larger than 5.

Output:

```
       data1
Johnny     1
Aisha      3
Sharon     2
```

I tried the way given in other stackoverflow, but it doesn't work.

*real data is way larger, >130 rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data1[data1 <= 5,,drop = FALSE]
```

or

```
data1[!data1 > 5,,drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: OMG! Why does this work?! I tried this before and it returns errors. Thanks man!